# presto replace multiple characters

Tags: sql, regex, string, replace, presto

I have a string and would like to remove a set of characters. Is there a better way than chaining multiple `replace()`?

I came up with the following but it requires a `replace()` call for each character:

```
WITH my_table(id, a_string) AS (
     VALUES
         (1, 'test{' || CHR(39) || '}xyz'),
         (2, 'x'),
         (3, '{y}'),
         (1, 'z'),
         (2, 'none'),
         (3, 'none' || CHR(39) || 'xyz')
)
SELECT replace(replace(replace(a_string,CHR(39)),'{'),'}') FROM my_table
```

This is a minimal example and I have more characters to escape so I was looking for a less verbose way of achieving this. I didn't find a string function in the documentation capable of this directly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_replace`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html?highlight=regexp_replace#regexp_replace) to remove multiple characters:

```
presto> WITH my_table(id, a_string) AS (
     ->      VALUES
     ->          (1, 'test{' || CHR(39) || '}xyz'),
     ->          (2, 'x'),
     ->          (3, '{y}'),
     ->          (1, 'z'),
     ->          (2, 'none'),
     ->          (3, 'none' || CHR(39) || 'xyz')
     -> )
     -> SELECT regexp_replace(a_string, '[{}'']') FROM my_table;
  _col0
---------
 testxyz
 x
 y
 z
 none
 nonexyz
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Nice that's exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't find any regex. Thanks again